# Which Ubuntu I should install on this laptop?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, nvidia

İm using windows 8 my system is :
İntel core2duo t6400 2.0 ghz 2mb cache
6 gb ddr3 1033 mhz ram
Nvidia 9600mGS Gpu
and i have 500 gb hdd 
i love to play games so i prefer windows 8 for games but i would lıke to use ubuntu for my daily use i am thinking to use it alongside with windows 8 it is possible right? should i install 12.04 or 13.04 also i use 64 bit windows so i should use 64bit ubuntu right? thank you for your answers

Comment: @Alvar, he is not asking for the differences in the Ubuntu Flavours. He is asking on which version of Ubuntu (either 12.04 or 13.04) should he install as stated in the part `should i install 12.04 or 13.04 also i use 64 bit windows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support Release (LTS) while 13.04 is a Regular Release.

If you want the latest and cutting edge technologies that Ubuntu has to offer, you may use 13.04 (or 13.10) but if you are looking for a tried and proven stable environment with continuous updates in the near future, I will stick with 12.04.

It will basically depend on your preference and the environment that you will be using your Ubuntu box. Take for example if I will be making a production server, I would rather install Ubuntu 12.04 (or any LTS Release) because of the updates that will come its way. However, if I will be using it on a daily basis, I may want to try the new and cutting edge technologies which will bring me to install the latest release.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer i will use ubuntu for only daily use  watch movies and internet surf so i am downloading 13.04 now but is my system enough for ubuntu ? beacuse ı was tried 12.04 before and it was feeling a bit laggy not smooth thanks again

Comment: Ubuntu's system requirements are quite modest according to the [System Requirements Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). The lag that you experienced before might be due to the fact that your video card drivers are not installed.

Comment: ok so now i am installing ubuntu alongside my windows 8 i am a pretty noob about ubuntu so thank you after install if i feel a lag again should i ask another question or should i ask it on this question ? again thanks

Comment: After installation, follow the steps on [this guide](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/) to install the drivers for your GPU.

Comment: If after installing the drivers for the GPU and it is still laggy, you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: thanks i finished install i choosed install alongside windows 8 but when it boot it automatically boot windows 8 it doesnt see ubuntu what should i do?

Comment: Seems either grub is not installed or is not working. Read on and try the steps [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176273)